# How to download a new Ubuntu .iso on a live USB

Tags: boot, 20.04, system-installation, usb, live-usb

I downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04 .iso file. The .iso file was corrupted, but I didn't check the checksum, so I made a live USB of the corrupted Ubuntu .iso file. Then I wiped my old Ubuntu. I want to partition. Now my previous is corrupted, but I can still run something on my live USB with the *Try Ubuntu without installing* option. When I tried to install Ubuntu it said `input/output error` and also said that your hard disk or CD is corrupted. I know that it is not corrupted, but I'm unable to install Ubuntu anyway, so now I can't do anything. The corrupted live Ubuntu USB seems to be working, but it still shows some errors anyway.

Comment: As long as you can run Ubuntu from your live USB drive, you can also mount a file system on another drive and download a new iso file to that location. - (If your RAM is big enough, you might even store the iso file there, but you must realize that it is temporary, so in that case you must use it to create a new boot drive before shutdown or reboot.)

Answer (score 2):

Delete everything on the useless corrupted Ubuntu live USB. Download the  Ubuntu .iso file again, and check its MD5 checksum with `md5sum` or its SHA256 checksum with `sha256sum`.

```
cd ~/Downloads/
md5sum ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso
```

Create a new Ubuntu live USB. There is an application on the Ubuntu live USB for creating a bootable Ubuntu live USB. The application is named Startup Disk Creator and it can be launched from the terminal with `usb-creator-gtk` . If you're running Startup Disk Creator from an Ubuntu live USB you need to find another portable drive on which to create the new Ubuntu installation media, so you don't overwrite the USB flash drive that you're running the Ubuntu live session from. If you intend to have two USB drives plugged in to the computer at the same time, you can tell which USB drive you're running the Ubuntu live session from by checking its Device name in the built-in Disks application before you plug the new USB drive into the computer.

Boot from the new Ubuntu live USB, and start the Ubuntu installer. Install Ubuntu again.